# Reading a 2d array with blank spaces into char

Tags: c++, arrays, char, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array that represents a map/maze that looks like this :

```
+-+-+-+-+-+
|         |
+-+ +-+ + +
|     | | |
+ +-+-+ + +
| |     |  
+-+ +-+-+-+
```

And I have the following code for reading that map :

```
char mapa[hlimit][wlimit];
for(int j=0;j<hlimit;j++)
    cin>>mapa[j];
```

also tried this :

```
char mapa[hlimit][wlimit];
for(int j=0;j<hlimit;j++)
    for(int k=0;k<wlimit;k++)
        cin>>mapa[j][k];
```

Both ways the for loop ends before I enter the whole map. I tried replacing the blank spaces in the map with dots and the input works flawlessly. So, how do I do the input with spaces? I tried cin.getline(mapa[j],wlimit) also, didn't work for me.

Comment: You may find the [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) member of that `istream` helpful, particularly in the second snippet. Or the `getline` method, or even `std::getline` to dump the line into the current row.

Comment: `std::istream` used with the `operator>>` skips whitespaces from input by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) suggesting using get() worked flawlessly. Here's my code :

```
char mapa[hlimit][wlimit];
for(int j=0;j<hlimit;j++)
{
    for(int k=0;k<wlimit;k++)
        mapa[j][k]=cin.get();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Be careful with possible exceptions thrown by istream::get : if your method is critical / needs exception safety, then you should try/catch the get() call.